# websites to force transit airport

Tags: online-resources, airports

I am planning a trip from hannover to paris but since i have the whole day i am looking for a website to force a ticket to make a transit on a chosen airport (for example london). 
eg: hannover - london then london - paris

is there a website that allows that ?

Comment: Use a multicity search

Comment: matrix with transit airport and /minconnect option - https://www.farefreaks.com/articles/read/9/ita-matrix-advanced-routing-codes

Comment: Or just look at flights Hannover-London then London Paris.

Comment: but it won't be considered as a transit and since i'm non european i'm gonna need a visa for that

Comment: Good question. I haven't found one but there should be a way. Even the opposite, avoiding a transit airport for those people who cannot obtain a visa for some locations.

Answer (score 1):

Well, look at it a different way, there's no need to 'force' a connection, just book an itinerary with a connection in a city you want.

Be aware though that the airline you want to fly might not offer that connection at all.  For example, there is no way to force Lufthansa to connect you in London.

If London is you preferred stopover, look at airlines that hub in the London area such as British Airways, Ryanair or EasyJet.